# Word for generating ideas or hypothesising that's not too academic or corporate killspeaky

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking to talk about the stage of a process where you generate ideas or potential solutions for testing later.  You could say hypothesis formation or ideation.  But the former is too academic for a commercial context and the latter has connotations of pretentious consultantese.  Looking for something a bit more plain English.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please have a look at the [help for single-word-requests](/tags/single-word-requests/info) since this sort of question often generates more heat than light.

Comment: See also [to put on one's thinking cap](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11228/to-put-on-the-thinking-cap/11230#11230).

Answer (score 4):

"*[Brainstorming](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainstorming)*" is a common word for generating ideas:

> a group problem-solving technique that involves the spontaneous contribution of ideas from all members of the group

> also : the mulling over of ideas by one or more individuals in an attempt to devise or find a solution to a problem

A more natural way of expressing this concept would be to say "*coming up with ideas*". Although not a single-word solution, it avoids any domain specific connotations.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too far on the other end of the spectrum from *hypothesizing*, but a common term for this activity is ***[spitballing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spitball)*** (M-W, 2nd entry). See this [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/idiom/spitballing/) entry for more background.